# ADB Shell mount/umount SD Card

Tags: android, linux, shell, mount

I'm trying to mount/unmount the SD card of my device.

Unmounting works fine. The problem is that everytime I try to mount the directory, i get te following message:

```
usage mount -r -w -o options -t type device directory
```

Steps taken:

1-Unmount the SD

```
umount /mnt/media_rw/extsd
```

2- cat /proc/self/mountinfo. Output:

```
50 1 179:1 / /mnt/media_rw/extsd rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime shared:19 - vfat /dev/block/vold/179:1 rw,dirsync,uid=1023,gid=1023,fmask=0007...etc
```

3 -Then i was trying to execute the command:

```
mount /dev/block/vold/179:1 /mnt/media_rw/extsd
```

And gettinig the previous error.

SOLUTION:

I made it work by executing:

mount -t vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/media_rw/extsd

Comment: In my opinion the first parameter to the `mount` command you have given is wrong. I assume you should have some other file in /dev (not in its sub-folder) which represents that SD card (i.e. /dev/sdd1). This file should be a node with 179, 1.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Inside /dev folder there is a bunch of files but I can't identify the one which represents the SDCard. How could I do this?

Comment: if you do `ls -l /dev/*`, pay attention to block device files named like sd*, mmc*. You need to know what driver handles your SD card, it will give the name, and its partition you need to mount, it will define the number.

Comment: I found these two files: mmcblk0 and mmcblk0p1. So i tried mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /storage/extsd and mount /dev/mmcblk0/storage/extsd. Both returned same error mentioned in OP

Comment: Try to create a mountpoint yourselef somewhere and mount over to there. Also: `mkdir /test` and `mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 /test`. If does not work - please give the output. In parallel check manual to your mount against mandatory parameters. UPDATED: `mount -r -t ext2 /dev/mmcblk0p1 /test` - assuming ext2 is the fs type at the sd card.

Comment: I've been able to mount/unmount from adb with this command: mount -t vfat /dev/block/mmcblk0p1 /mnt/media_rw/extsd. Seems that adding the type makes it work. Great help!

Comment: Now the problem is that the SO does not detect that mount/umount operations. I think i should send a broadcast

Answer (score -1):

Here is some relevant info which should help: Find the right device name of an SD card connected via a USB card reader:

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/3800/find-the-right-device-name-of-an-sd-card-connected-via-a-usb-card-reader